# Передать значение переменной из одной активити в другую

Tags: java, android, activity

Есть первый класс в котором есть переменная NameUser

Есть второй класс в котором есть также переменная NameUser

Из первого класса значение переменой NameUser нужно передать в переменную NameUser второго класса.

Как сделать?

Первый класс

```
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.widget.TextView;

  public class HealthScreen extends AppCompatActivity{

TextView textView;

String NameUser;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_health_screen);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);

    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity();

    NameUser = mainActivity.NameUser;

    textView.setText(NameUser);
}
```

}

Второй класс

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView WelcomeAlpha;
Button OK;
Button OK1;

ImageView line1;

TextView FIO;
TextView text_Weigth;
EditText NameEdit;
EditText WeigthEdit;

Animation animation;
Animation animation1;
Animation animation2;

String NameUser;
String WeightUser;

int timer = 0;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadein);
    animation1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadeout);
    animation2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.fadenow);

    line1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.line);

    WelcomeAlpha = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_text_view);
    OK = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
    OK1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button_2);

    FIO = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.FIO);
    text_Weigth = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    NameEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
    WeigthEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);

    WelcomeAlpha.startAnimation(animation);
    line1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    NameEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    WeigthEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    OK.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    OK1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    FIO.startAnimation(animation2);
    text_Weigth.startAnimation(animation2);
    WeigthEdit.startAnimation(animation2);
    NameEdit.startAnimation(animation2);


    View.OnClickListener onClickListener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            WelcomeAlpha.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OK.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NameEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            NameEdit.startAnimation(animation);
            OK.startAnimation(animation);
            FIO.startAnimation(animation);

        }
    };
    WelcomeAlpha.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    View.OnClickListener onClickListener1 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            NameUser = NameEdit.getText().toString();
            line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            line1.startAnimation(animation);
            OK1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            OK.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            WeigthEdit.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            WeigthEdit.startAnimation(animation);
            OK1.startAnimation(animation);
            text_Weigth.startAnimation(animation);

        }
    };
    OK.setOnClickListener(onClickListener1);

    View.OnClickListener onClickListener2 = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            WeightUser = WeigthEdit.getText().toString();
            NameEdit.startAnimation(animation1);
            WeigthEdit.startAnimation(animation1);
            OK1.startAnimation(animation1);
            WeigthEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            NameEdit.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OK1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            OK1.setClickable(false);

            NameEdit.setActivated(false);
            WeigthEdit.setActivated(false);
            line1.startAnimation(animation1);
            text_Weigth.startAnimation(animation1);
            FIO.startAnimation(animation1);
            GoToHealth();
        }
    };
    OK1.setOnClickListener(onClickListener2);
}
void GoToHealth()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HealthScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: код покажите. Надо значть, как эти классы взаимосвязаны

Comment: @metalurgus правил вопрос

Comment: Передайте его через Intent при старте второго Activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Сделать публичный метод `public string getUserName()`, который будет возвращать `userName` (`return userName;`), и вызвать его в другом методе:

   ```
   ClassWithVariable instance=new ClassWithVariable(); //создаете экземпляр класса
   String name = instance.getUserName(); //получаете переменную.
   ```
2. Сделать публичный метод в классе, куда необходимо передать переменную, который принимает её в качестве аргумента:

   ```
   class MyClass {
       public void method(String userName); 
   }

   class ClassWithVariable {
       private string userName = "Ivan";

       MyClass instance = new MyClass();
       instance.method(userName);
   }
   ```

Comment: В твоём случае используй публичное свойство)

Comment: @Ker_Jen В случае с активити (а в вопросе речь идет именно о активити) это решение - костыль , причем проблемный, так как существование невидимой в данный момент активити, а соответственно и ее полей, ничем не гарантировано. Правильное решение - передавать данные через `Intent`, интерфейс  или какую то шину, вроде EventBus/